# how do I start jquery animation from a different point?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm animating a rectangle in jQuery to go from `width:0px, heihgt:0px;` to `width:564px; height:264px;`.

The animation is starting from the top-left corner, is it possible to start the animation from the bottom left corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to position the rectangle so that its origin is the bottom left. You could use absolute positioning.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For animation bottom left corner, height should be `window.height()` at initial point..